# Read random string from a file without reading all file

Tags: c#, file, io

how to read a random line from a file without reading all the file?

I tried `FileStream` class and Seek, Read functions. But didn't get luck with 100% working method.

Comment: Please show that code that you have tried and explain what you mean by "didn't get luck with 100% working method"

Comment: How do you want to know how many lines the file has without reading all lines? You need to know the line count if you want to pick a _random_ line.

Comment: How would you know where to position? How would you know where the lines start and end?

Comment: Can you read it once and index the location of the lines?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as a line is defined by a carriage return or line break. There is no way to know how many lines there are in the file without reading all of it unless you know something about the structure of the file; for example, that every line is 80 characters. In that case you're picking a random 80 characters from a file of length N, in which case your `FileStream` seek is the way to go.